# How will Azure Api Apps accept SSL certificates with wildcard

Tags: azure, ssl, wildcard, azure-api-apps

We are trying to make our .NET Api App on Azure secure (https). We already set a custom domain name like abc.dev.mydomain.io. This runs fine as on calling http://abc.dev.mydomain.io our api app is answering.
After this step we uploaded succesful a certificate. When we now trying to bind the ceritificate to abc.dev.mydomain.io an error occurs like "Certificate with fingerprint xxx do not match hostname abc.dev.mydomain.io". On checking in azure portal the uploaded certificate shows correctly our wildcard domain "*.mydomain.io".
Any idea about that?
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that your certificate doesn't match your domain!

You would need a `*.*.example.com` certificate to match `abc.dev.example.com.`

A `*.example.com` is intended to match `www.example.com`, `dev.example.com` etc.

Comment: Perfect and obviously ;-) Thanks for the hint!!